Spring Framework Project in Kotlin Failing with `IllegalAccessError` During `kaptGenerateStubsKotlin` Task
I am building a Spring Framework project in Kotlin and encountering an IllegalAccessError during the kaptGenerateStubsKotlin task when running ./gradlew bootRun. Here are the details of the error:


 
> Task :kaptGenerateStubsKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaCompiler (in unnamed module @0x514acdca) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.main to unnamed module @0x514acdca
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.<init>(KaptContext.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContextForStubGeneration.<init>(KaptContextForStubGeneration.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.contextForStubGeneration(Kapt3Extension.kt:295)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:174)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:256)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:247)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:87)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:168)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:460)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:62)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:476)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:399)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:280)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:636)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1598)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Errors were stored into /home/aditya/Partition/Radar/ManagementPortal/.gradle/kotlin/errors/errors-1722250119988.log

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':kaptGenerateStubsKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Internal compiler error. See log for more details

I have two modules inside this project, and the configurations are as follows:
Root Project:
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.9.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.9.10"
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.9.10' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.9.10"
}

tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    compilerOptions {
        jvmTarget = JvmTarget.JVM_17
        apiVersion = KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_1_8
        languageVersion = KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_1_8
    }
}

Submodule auth:
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    compilerOptions {
        jvmTarget = JvmTarget.JVM_11
        apiVersion = KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_1_8
        languageVersion = KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_1_8
    }
}

Submodule app-client:
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    compilerOptions {
        jvmTarget = JvmTarget.JVM_11
        apiVersion = KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_1_7
        languageVersion = KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_1_9
    }
}

I encounter this error when running the ./gradlew bootRun command.
Steps I Have Taken:
Tried running the command with Java 21, 17, and 11 in IntelliJ Project Structure dialog.
Followed various solutions from Stack Overflow and other forums but have not been able to resolve the issue.
Environment:
IntelliJ IDEA
Java 21, 17, and 11 (installed locally)
Gradle
Kotlin version: 1.9.10
Spring Framework

I have verified the Gradle configurations and plugin versions.
The project contains mixed Java versions due to different module requirements.
